# ImageCreateFromJPEG PHP Another image

Tags: php, image

How do you add another image to a image in php the itme i want to add is images/rank1.jpg?

```
 $rImg = ImageCreateFromJPEG("images/card/test.jpg");
 $cor = imagecolorallocate($rImg, 255, 255, 255); 
 imagestring($rImg,5,60,3,$username,$cor);
```

Comment: I have tryed to use 
imagecopymerge($rImg, $image, 600, 400, 300, 22, 100, 47, 75);
still cant get it to work

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific if you want help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the imagecopy...() functions like [imagecopyresampled()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php).

The User Contributed Notes in the Manual provide lots of examples. If you want to add watermarks with transparency, [this](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php#93166) might work for you.